# Stopping downloads

Tags: applications, download-manager

I have an LG G4 phone that doesn't have Download Manager enabled.
It started downloading something on its own, even though Play Store is set for "do not auto-update apps". How can I stop this download?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the notification pulldown? Is it downloading new apps to the phone, or updating existing ones?